# Getting a Mapping error when trying to Retrieve a list of strings

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Im currently following a YouTube video that's a bit of a dart crash course, so do forgive me for what may be my lack of knowledge here. Im trying to use mapping in order to create a question widget with its own set of answers, changing to a new question with new answers upon a user clicking. Here's my code for my Main class, class for the answer widget, and question widget as well. My issue is coming at line 49 of my main class
( questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']), where I'm getting an error saying "The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. Cant seem to find a solution to this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Main:

```
void answerQuestions() {
  setState(() {
    _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
  });
  print(_questionIndex);
}

var questions = [
  {
    'questionText': 'what is your favorite color',
    'answers': ['black', 'red', 'green' 'white'],
  },
  {
    'questionText': 'what is your favorite animal',
    'answers': ['Giraffe' 'Lion', 'Snake', 'Gorilla'],
  },
  {
    'questionText': 'what is your favorite brand',
    'answers': ['Polo' 'BBC', 'YSL', 'Jordan'],
  },
];
return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(
              questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'],
            ),
            answer(answerQuestions),
            answer(answerQuestions),
            answer(answerQuestions),
          ],
        )));
```

}

Answer:

```
class answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback selectHandler;

  answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Answer1'),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          onPrimary: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Question:

```
class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  late final String questionText;

  Question(this.questionText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          questionText,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what your `questions` variable looks like to dart:

```
[
  {
    'some string': <SOMETHING>
    ...
  }
  ...
]
```

So basically it is a list of maps and each map has a `string` key and something else as a value. So when you read `questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']` You as the developer know that `questionText` is a String, but dart has no idea what it might be. To tell dart that it is a string, you can use the `as` keyword:

```
Question(
  questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] as String,
),
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! And thanks for the explanation as well.